# Creating an LSTM Network with Custom Initialization from Linear Transformations in TensorFlow 2

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0

I want to make an RNN network of type LSTM with an input tensor and two initial states initialized by computing two linear transformations. The first one is of shape TensorShape([256, 10]) and the second is of shape TensorShape([12, 10]).
The initial states are computed with the code mentioned below:

```
inputs_pc = tf.keras.Input(shape=(init_pc.shape[0]*init_pc.shape[1],))
d = tf.keras.layers.Dense(init_pc.shape[0]*init_pc.shape[1])
x_pc = d(inputs_pc)

inputs_hd = tf.keras.Input(shape=(init_hd.shape[0]*init_hd.shape[1],))
d = tf.keras.layers.Dense(init_hd.shape[0]*init_hd.shape[1])
x_hd = d(inputs_hd)
initialization_pc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(x_pc)
initialization_hd = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(x_hd)
```

What is the code to perform an LSTM of 128 units with the initialization of the tensor [initialization_pc, initialization_hd]?